# upgrading to rails 5.1.2 from rails 4.20 breaks Angular integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, haml, ng-annotate

I am upgrading my rails 4.2.0 app to 5.1.2 which is going fine.  I had used Angular 1.x to enhance my rails app pages selectively.  My rails views are in HAML.  Here is a snippet of a page which loads fine in 4.2.0, but not in 5.1.2:

```
.well{"ng-app" => "billing", "ng-controller" => "BillableCtrl"}
  = simple_form_for @billable do |f|
    .row
      .col-md-4
```

This loads angular fine in this view.  However, I get the following stack trace in my javascript console when I try to load this in Rails 5.1.2.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
>   angular.self-26d045c60a96c782aa8ef9f5709b1b4fd1ec8578bc37ec2c6c2b9c4370f4bac0.js?body=1:64
>   Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   billing due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'billing' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

I am using ngannotate-rails version 1.2.2 in rails 5.1.2 upgrade.  The version of ngannotate-rails used in rails 4.2.0 version was 0.15.4.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  What are some options to investigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out NOT to be an angular problem but a Rails to Javascript messaging problem.  Take a look at the following line code in one of my javascript functions:

$scope.billable_item = #{@billable.to_json};

Up until Rails 4.2.0 in my experience, this was the standard way to pass the Rails data into javascript.  However, for some reason that I do not understand yet, it is broken.  That was causing Angular to throw very confusing messages.  I have been using the 'Gon' gem to pass data from Rails to Javascript for some time and I switched to that which worked fine.  I will now switch my entire Rails to Javascript communication to the Gon gem.